# How to edit a table view cell's text in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I am trying to design a settings screen. I added a table vc in my storyboard and changed it to static cells. Then I configured the number of sections and the number of cells in each section.

Now I want to add text to each of the table view cells. I tried to select the cell and edit the text property in the property inspector. But I could not find a text property. I then tried to drag a label to the cells' content views. But I can't put the label in exactly the same place as the others. Also this method is very tedious.

I mean there is even a property called `textLabel` in `UITableViewCell` class! How can there not be a corresponding property in the interface builder?

How can I do this in IB? Must I use code to set the text of each cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you selected Style: Basic at the Cell's Attribute inspector, and then select the label.
Also, because of the cell has a contentView, the easiest way is to find it in the view hierarchy, or click on the cell until you see the inspector of the label

[image: Inspector]